# Save Files Immediately

Tags: usb, encryption, container, veracrypt

I have a Veracrypt container on a USB 2.0 drive (not full-disk encryption).

When I copy a file from my hard-drive (where Ubuntu is installed) to inside the Veracrypt container, the standard copying dialog appears.

However, the files I want to copy haven't begun to be written to the USB until I dismount the Veracrypt container. This sometimes takes a while before I can remove the physical USB safely (moving multiple GBs of content to USB 2.0).

**How can I have it write to the disk immediately (or at least sooner) than when I dismount the Veracrypt container?**

Comment: Type "sync" after you've made significant changes/edits.

Comment: But isn't running `sudo sync DEVICE` harmful to the USB?

Comment: Command `sync` does not have parameter DEVICE. Just sync. It is not harmful to any writable device, except that writes to flash memory causes wearing.

Comment: @ddbug Just verified that `sync` works. Add it as an answer, and I'll accept it. (You may want to link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48235/can-i-watch-the-progress-of-a-sync-operation which shows how to monitor the progress)